# Convert String containing comma separated JSONObjects to JSONArray

Tags: java

I have a String which contains many JSONObjects. I need to convert that String to JSONArray. Please help.

```
""{\""Name\"":\""name1\"",\""Age\"":\""20\"",\""S.No.\"":\""1\""},
 {\""Name\"":\""name2\"",\""Age\"":\""21\"",\""S.No.\"":\""2\""},
 {\""Name\"":\""name3\"",\""Age\"":\""22\"",\""S.No.\"":\""3\""}""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the string in `"[]"` and then use the JSON parser of your choice.

Comment: Thank you.. 
after adding "[ ]" to the String,  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(string); converts the string to JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

There is Java Lib called Quick-json - A java library to convert json string to java objects & java objects to json string. parse/generate json the way you want quickly. configure/validate json at every level.

Please refer for Quick- Json Lib https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/ has good example's as well as explanation.